# SIGSTOP and SIGTSTP can damage the JVM?

Tags: java, linux, jvm, signals, jvm-hotspot

In Linux there are two different signals that can be used to pause a process, *SIGSTOP* and *SIGTSTP*. Both are not handled by the *HotSpot Virtual Machine*, *SIGSTOP* because cannot be caught and *SIGTSTP* [because is not handled by *HotSpot*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/signals-139944.html#gbzbl). I would like to know if it is safe to send those two signals or, in case it is not safe, what part of the *JVM* would be affected (e.g. the garbage collector). Note that I don't care about the problems that the program running on the *JVM* could have, I'm specifically interested in the internals of the *JVM*. Is it safe to send a *STOP/TSTP* to the *JVM* ?

Comment: If `SIGTSTP` could damage it, it would be a serious bug, honestly; I have never had any problems suspending Java command line programs at the terminal, so I don't think `SIGTSTP` is a problem at all.

Answer (score 4):

`SIGSTOP` and `SIGTSTP` are not included in HotSpot JVM's [signal handling](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/signals-139944.html#gbzbl) doesn't mean HotSpot JVM doesn't support them.

It only means there is no special handling for those two signals. Some signals(`SIGSEGV`, `SIGTERM`, etc) are specially handled by HotSpot JVM to implement [certain features](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/signals-139944.html#gbzbl) (implicit null check, shutdown hooks, etc).

The ones not specially handled, they will behave the **default way**. Hence when HotSpot receives `SIGSTOP` and `SIGTSTP`, it will behave the the default way, which means **Pause** and **Terminal Pause**.

In fact, `SIGSTOP` cannot be ignored. From signal(7)'s [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html):

> The signals `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored.

We can demonstrate this by a simple C program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main()
{
  while(1)
  {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    usleep(900000);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

There is no signal handling what so ever for `SIGSTOP` or `SIGTSTP`, but still you can send them to this simple program and they will behave correctly.

By pressing Ctrl+Z will send a `SIGTSTP` signal and by run `kill -19 pid` will send a `SIGSTOP` signal. And the demo program will pause.

In both cases, running a `kill -18 pid` will send `SIGCONT` signal and bring our demo program back to execution.

Comment: Just curious on top of the answer. Will the sleep time continues after the unpause. Ex: if Thread.sleep is 10 seconds, if we pause for 5 seconds, will it sleep for 10 seconds or 5 seconds after unpause?

Comment: sleep simply removes a process from RUNQUEUE for a period of time. When the sleep has expired the scheduler puts it back to the RUNQUEUE. so to answer you, yes the sleep time continues even though the process is paused. For a sleep of 10 seconds, if you pause a process at the 5th second of its sleep for the next 10 seconds then by the time you resume the process it is ready to be run